# What does basis point mean?

Tags: bonds, credit, security

S&P's schedule of costs mention that getting a rating from them currently costs "6.25 basis points" of the offering.

Does this literally mean 6.25%? As in if the bond produced was 100 million in size, the issuing company (or whoever was paying for the rating) would have to pay 6.25 million?

Comment: "Basis point: one hundredth of one percent", so 6.25 basis points on 100 million would be $62,500.

Comment: "I was considering issuing a bunch of debt backed by nothing so therefore it is related to personal finance."  Huh????

Comment: Nate - I'm just guessing that was a bit of a joke. Aside from that "what is a basis point" is a valid question if we haven't answered it yet.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer. If that the reason to keep it (and I agree that's a valid question), it might be a good idea to change the title line...?

Comment: @keshlam - good idea, sir. Done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [Investopedia](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/b/basispoint.asp):

> One basis point is equal to 1/100th of 1%, or 0.01% (0.0001)

Thus, if S&P charges 6.25 basis points to rate a bond and the bond is $100 million, this will cost you $62,500.

(I'm not sure you can actually issue a bond as a not-super-wealthy individual, but I suppose there's nothing stopping you from trying)

Answer (score 3):

FYI, the term exists to solve the following language problem when discussing percentages:

> Alice: I got a loan at 5% APR.  But if I ever miss a payment the rate goes up 2%.
>
> Bob: That's it?  5.1% doesn't seem all that bad.
>
> Alice: No, it goes up to 7%.
>
> Bob: Oh, you mean it goes up 40%.
>
> Alice: ACK!

Because `percent` can be a unit just like `meter` or `orange`, a term is needed to distinguish when you're talking about the unit called `percent` vs. the mathematical operation called *percent*, especially when you need to use them in the same sentence.  So `basis point` means 1/100 of the unit called `percent` (the same way `centimeter` means 1/100 of the unit called `meter`).  Alice and Bob can then avoid confusion by using only one meaning of the word "percent" at a time:

> Alice: I got a loan at 5% APR.  But if I ever miss a payment the rate goes up by 200 basis points.
>
> Bob: Yikes, to 7%!
>
> Alice: Yep.

or:

> Alice: I got a loan at 500 basis points APR.  But if I ever miss a payment the rate goes up by 40%.
>
> Bob: Yikes, to 700 basis points!
>
> Alice: Yep.

Comment: thanks! this helps with the terminology I hear colloquially